# Rotate log lost old file on centos 7.3

Tags: centos7, logrotate

I had config rotate log daily for apache.

When new day comes, example 00:00AM today (07/31/2017), new access.log file created, old access.log file changed to access.log-31072017

The problem here, tomorrow, access.log file will change to access.log-01082017 (yes), new access.log will create (yes), but access.log-31072017 file lost (ouch).

And, I performed:

```
vi /etc/logrotate.d/httpd
```

Insert end of file

```
/home/*/logs/*log{
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    delaycompress
    postrotate
        /bin/systemctl reload httpd.service > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

Rotate config

```
vi /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Change `weekly` to `daily`

Change `rotate 4` to `rotate 1`

The Log file is recorded at the `/home/example.com/logs/` path

How to retain the files of the previous days

Thank advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the value `rotate` in */etc/logrotate.conf* back to 4. Despite the comment in *logrotate.conf* it is not the number of weeks the logs are kept but the number of times the files are rotated before they are deleted.

The manpage for logrotate.conf explains this more clearly:

> **rotate** *count*
>
> Log  files  are  rotated  count  times before being removed or mailed to the address specified in a mail directive. If count is 0, old versions are removed
>   rather than rotated. Default is 0.

Setting it to 4 should keep the old logs for four days.